# Limit the inode cache used by a command

Tags: linux, memory, cache, limit, inode

I want to run a task with limits on the kernel objects that they will indirectly trigger. Note that this is not about the memory, threads, etc. used by the application, but about memory used by the kernel. Specifically, I want to limit the amount of **inode cache** that the task can use.

My motivating example is `updatedb`. It can use a considerable amount of inode cache, for things that mostly won't be needed afterwards. Specifically, I want to limit the value that is indicated by the `ext4_inode_cache` line in `/proc/slabinfo`. (Note that this is not included in the “buffers” or “cache” lines shown by `free`: that's only file content cache, the slab content is kernel memory and recorded in the “used” column.)

`echo 2 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` afterwards frees the cache, but that doesn't do me any good: the useless stuff has displaced things that I wanted to keep in memory, such as running applications and their frequently-used files.

The system is Linux with a recent (≥ 3.8) kernel. I can use root access to set things up.

How can I run a command in a limited environment (a container?) such that the contribution of that environment to the (ext4) inode cache is limited to a value that I set?

Comment: You might be able to use a container to do this.   Also, which "updatedb" are you running?  That is, which package?

Comment: @JamesYoungman Either GNU findutils or mlocate. Why does it matter?

Comment: Because I'm the maintainer of one of those.  GNU updatedb traverses the file system with `find`.   But find has no mechanism which would allow this to be controlled.

Comment: @James Youngman:  There is no possible way that a container or any VM could access the disk without the request being passed to the host kernel, so that would have no impact at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following my own question on [LKML](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/ce330972-78e6-4347-9735-72ee7bb21ef5@pmhahn.de/) this can be archived using [Control Group v2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.13/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html#):

## Pre-requisits

1. Make sure your Linux kernel has `MEMCG_KMEM` enabled, e.g. `grep CONFIG_MEMCG_KMEM "/boot/config-$(uname -r)"`
2. Depending on the OS (and `systemd` version) enable the use of `cgroups2` by specifying `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1` on the Linux kernel command line, e.g. via `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
3. Make sure the `cgroup2` file system is mounted on `/sys/fs/cgroup/`, e.g. `mount -t cgroup2 none /sys/fs/cgroup` or the equivalent in `/etc/fstab`. (`systemd` will do this for you automatically by default)

## Invocation

4. Create a new group `my-find` (once per boot) for your process: `mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/my-find`
5. Attach the (current) process (and all its future child processes) to that group: `echo $$ >/sys/fs/cgroup/my-find/cgroup.procs`
6. Configure a soft-limit, e.g. 2 MiB: `echo 2M >/sys/fs/cgroup/my-find/memory.high`

Finding the right value requires tuning and experimenting. You can get the current values from `memory.current` and/or `memory.stat`. Over time you should see `high` incrementing in `memory.events`, as the Linux kernel is now repeatedly forces to shrink the caches.

## Appendix

Notice that the limit applies *both* to user-space memory and kernel memory. It also applies to *all* processes of the group, which includes child-processes started by `updatedb`, which basically does a `find | sort | frcode`, where:

- `find` is the program trashing the `dentry` and `inode` caches, which we want to constrain. Otherwise its user-space memory requirement (theoretically) is constant.
- `sort` want lots of memory, otherwise it will fall back to using temporary files, which will result in additional IO.
- `frcode` will write the result to disk - e.g. a single file - which requires constant memory.

So basically you should put only `find` into a separate `cgroup` to limit its cache trashing, but not `sort` and `frcode`.

## Post scriptum

It does not work with `cgroup v1` as setting `memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes` is both deprecated and results in an "out-of-memory" event as soon as the processes go over the configured limit, which gets your processes killed immediately instead of forcing the Linux kernel to shrink the memory usage by dropping old data.
Quoting from section [CONFIG_MEMCG_KMEM](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.13/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/memory.html#kernel-memory-extension-config-memcg-kmem)

> Currently no soft limit is implemented for kernel memory. It is future work to trigger slab reclaim when those limits are reached.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [kernel's inode source code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/inode.c), you can see that the ihash_entries is set at the kernel level only.

There is no user or process level considerations at all.  Adding those could drastically decrease performance which would be counter productive.

It would also imply keeping track of all processes that used the cached entries, therefore using more memory to do it.

The bottom line is that it is simply not possible with the current kernel, nor would it be a good idea to implement it.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with its not being a good idea: Linux virtualizes (containerizes) a lot of things, why not cache?

Comment: That is not the point.  To be able to limit the inode cache per process, a list of inodes used per process is needed which would consume more memory than what the OP is trying to restrain.

Comment: The only way it would be possible is if the container were to have exclusive access to certain hardware, which would defeat the point of containers.